# AttributeError: 'InstalledAppFlow' object has no attribute 'run_console'

Tags: python, oauth, google-colaboratory

I have created a Flask web app in Google Colab, and I have a sign in button to call for the Google Oauth for sign in into the app. Following is my code.

App.py

```
from flask import (Flask, render_template, request, url_for, session,
                   abort, redirect, g)
import os
import pprint

import google.oauth2.credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)

template_folder = '/content/drive/MyDrive/templates'
static_folder='/content/drive/MyDrive/static'

app = Flask(__name__,
            template_folder = template_folder,
            static_folder = static_folder)
app.secret_key = ""

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'drive'
API_VERSION = 'v3'

@app.route("/login")
def get_authenticated_service():
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
  credentials = flow.run_console()
  return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)

def list_drive_files(service, **kwargs):
  results = service.files().list(
    **kwargs
  ).execute()

  pp.pprint(results)

@app.route("/favicon.ico")
def favicon():
    return url_for('static', filename='data:,')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
  service = get_authenticated_service()
  list_drive_files(service,
                   orderBy='modifiedByMeTime desc',
                   pageSize=5)
```

index.html

```
<div id="id01" class="modal">
<div class="container">
     <h1>Sign in with Google</h1>
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    <button><a href='/login'><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='image/google-icon.png')}}">   Continue with Google</button>
</div>
```

I have two question:

1. When the user click the signin button, the app should directed the user to Sign in with Google, rather print a link in the terminal.
2. After th user have signed in, it show an error as follow:
   Error 403: access_denied
   Request details: access_type=offline response_type=code redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob state=rGRjgwGIvIZLNVlI8Jffw2xphBEiaG prompt=consent client_id=313774913031-3piaotrcvd2tg11q6t85ru6ji6nvimcu.apps.googleusercontent.com scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly

   What should I do?

Comment: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob <--- doesnt work anymore try changing it to localhost  TBH thats not the code i use for flask at all looks more like installed app code not web app code

Comment: The usual Google Oauth does not work out in Google Colab. It show an error Http 500

Comment: I dont think your going to get this to work with flask.  Its an issue with the redirect uri even with Ngrok i think its going to be strange.

Comment: Installed flow wont work either as I am getting raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")   Thats because it wants to open the consent screen on the machine the colab is running on.   Back to trying web

Comment: I got an issue of redirect url in Google Cloud Console, as the Flask run on colab which is totally different from run on local computer!

Comment: Yeah that's what I added ngrok the it will run or it should I'm still working on it